# Spring JPA - Stackoverflow exception on updating Owning end of OnetoOne relation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a `one-to-one` mapping between two Objects.

**UserDO.java:**

```
public class UserDO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull(message = "Username can not be null!")
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull(message = "Password can not be null!")
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean deleted = false;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private OnlineStatus onlineStatus;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private ZonedDateTime dateCreated = ZonedDateTime.now();

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private CardDO card;

}
```

**CardDO.java:**

```
public class CardDO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long pan;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    private LocalDate expirationDate;


    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private CardType cardType;


    @Column(nullable = false)
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private ZonedDateTime dateCreated = ZonedDateTime.now();

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="card")
    private UserDO user;

}
```

Now, when i link the two up first time and save the user object in repo it works fine but everytime when i try to update the user object, it throws StackOverFlow exception.

Code for linking the 2 objects up:

```
userDO.setCard(cardDO);
userRepository.save(userDO);
```

Code for updating:

```
UserDO userDO = findUser(userId);
userDO.setOnlineStatus(onlineStatus);
userRepository.save(userDO);
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Could you show stacktrace of the Exception?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set owning site of the relation:

```
public class CardDO {
    //skipped

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="card", insertable = false, updateable = false)
    private UserDO user;
}
```

and

```
@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinColumn(name = card_id)
private CardDO card;
```

Hibernate dirty check mechanism sees that `CardDO` is updated so wants to update `User`. Then `Card`, then `User` etc.

Comment: When i do this, IDE complains: cannot resolve method 'insertable' / 'updatable' . So i tried this:

@OneToOne(mappedBy="card")
@JoinColumn( insertable = false, updatable = false)
 private UserDO user;

Still throwing exception: 

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
 at ee.neocard.domainobject.UserDO.hashCode(UserDO.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
 at ee.neocard.domainobject.CardDO.hashCode(CardDO.java:16) ~[classes/:na]

Answer (score 0):

I am able to run your code with some minor changes in annotations like below

**UserDO.java**

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;

@Entity
public class UserDO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull(message = "Username can not be null!")
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull(message = "Password can not be null!")
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean deleted = false;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private OnlineStatus onlineStatus;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private ZonedDateTime dateCreated = ZonedDateTime.now();

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private CardDO card;
}
```

**CardDO.java**

```
    import java.time.LocalDate;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;

@Entity
public class CardDO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long pan;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    private LocalDate expirationDate;


    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private CardType cardType;


    @Column(nullable = false)
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private ZonedDateTime dateCreated = ZonedDateTime.now();

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToOne
    private UserDO user;
}
```

If you save data using below code `userId` can not be saved in your `cartdo` entity

```
userDO.setCard(cardDO);
userRepository.save(userDO);
```

If you want to save `userId` also in your `cartdo` entity you have to hit your rest api through `postman` and send data in your api like below

```
{
    "username":"vishal",
    "password":"123456",
    "onlineStatus":"OFFLINE",
    "cardDO" :{
        "cardType":"NEW",
        "pan":"2"
    }
}
```

I am not sending value of `datecreated` and `expirationdate` because i removed these fields from my entity for easy observation of the problem.
After storing data through postman you can check the table of `carddo` in the `database` there is a `user_id` and it is not null.

And when you are going to update first find using `findOne` method of `CrudRepository` and then save like below code. In this code i am also able to update `cardType` that is belongs from `CardDO.java` entity

```
UserDO userDO = repository.findOne(userId);
    CardDO card = userDO.getCard();
    card.setCardType(CardType.OLD);
    userDO.setOnlineStatus(OnlineStatus.ONLINE);
    userDO.setCard(card);
    repository.save(userDO);
```

Comment: I posted the updated answer please check it and let me know if it is working.

Comment: Now you can use this code because now i am able to do save and update both of the entities.

Comment: With this, CardDO doesn't even seem to keep reference to the UserDO. Every time I add a card to the user, I check if it's assigned to any other user, and now it's always returning null.

Comment: You mean in card entity userId always null.

Comment: If you want to save userId also in your cartdo entity you have to hit your rest api through postman. I have created a controller and rest api for storing data.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting stackoverflow exception because you have declared `@OneToOne` mapping in both `UserDO` and `CardDO` for each other. So when 
You exceute method like `findOne()` of userRepository , it will give you `UserDO` object but this object has `@oneToOne` mapping to `CardDo` so the object of `CardDo` will be fetch from database at the same time. Since your `CardDo` object has `@OneToOne` mapping with `UserDO` so same thing happen i.e `UserDo` object is fetched from database . This will make a infinite loop and leads to `stackoverflow exception`.

I would suggest to use below code in your `CardDo` entity:

```
private Long userId;
```

instead of doing `@oneToOne` mapping:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="card")
private UserDO user;
```

Comment: I only get StackOverflow when I update the UserDO object. I can fetch the UserDO object containing CardDO without any error.